# Thread.isInterrupted() return true at first time then return false?

Tags: java

```
   public static void main(String... args){
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        logger.warn("{}", Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());//true
        logger.warn("{}", Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());//false
}
```

As the result shows: the first call of `isInterrupted()` return `true`, the second call of `isInterrupted()` return false, I read the DOC of `Thread.isInterrupted()` said:`Tests whether this thread has been interrupted.  The <i>interrupted status</i> of the thread is unaffected by this method.`

so why the second and following call of `isInterrupted()` return false, it should always return true no matter how many times of `isInterrupted()` was called according to the DOC.

Comment: Which version of Java do you use? It seems in Java 11 [isInterrupted](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted()) should not clear the interrupted flag (but [interrupted](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted()) should.)

Comment: @GáborBakos, open jdk 1.8.0_181

Comment: Which logging framework? That is doing io so it is probably resetting the flag. https://ideone.com/91B8te that example shows successive calls to isInterrupted.

Comment: @matt, wow, you are right, I change `logger` to `system.out.println()`, it always print `true` , thanks very much. BTW I use logback logger framework.

Comment: @matt, I use logback 1.1.3, this issue is fixed in newer versions(1.1.11+, maybe other versions also fixed but I did not test them all).